# Is there a way to enable css intellisense for language extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If I'm making a language extension for postcss, is there a way to enable CSS intellisense for this language? For example if I type "ma", it shows all possible rules starting with "ma".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone curious about the answer, i opened an issue on github and [recieved response](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25795) by the dev.